# How To get around certain email clients when viewing html code

Tags: html, css, email

I am building out an email, and I wanted to use `position:relative` to position the links where I need them to be. The only issue is iphones are affected by this change. I would like to be able to exclude IOS from seeing this change and for them to see my code without the position tag. **Is there any way to exclude iphones from a CSS property?**

I've tested my code on litmus and every email client works except for all of the iphones. The ipads work and all of the major email clients work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible if you use a CSS media query. To use CSS for non IOS devices, use the following media query:

```
@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
}
```

also, to do CSS for IOS devices only, you can use:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}
```

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thank you! That helps even better than my current fix

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! One quick word of advice: it's against site etiquette to say "thank you." It may seem counter-intuitive, but it's to stop comment sections being clogged up, hiding more useful comments like clarification. The best way to thank someone is to accept their answer by pressing the green tick (this will give you 2 reputation and the answerer 15 reputation) and upvoting